# Is the proof-of-work algorithm "Quark" insecure?

Tags: cryptocurrency, proof-of-work

I recently found out about Quark [here](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Quark_Algorithm).

Apparently it is a proof-of-work algorithm used by several cryptocurrencies and is based on a single-level hash function, which consists of 9 different levels of encryption by six cryptographic algorithms. It also says that Quark provides a "64-bit" protection against hackers.

Isn't 64-bits of protection considered rather insecure? I'm sure a hacker with sufficient computing power can break 64-bits of security given enough time and money. Or am I missing something?

Comment: 32-bit collision resistance is surely inadequate, but to prove you've done $2^{64}$ work can sometimes exceed the capability of moderately sized high-end computers.

Answer (score 1):

Quark's overblown security assurances do not add up.  Here is how they do testing and code review (see their [Github page](https://github.com/quark-project/quark)):

> Testing and code review is the bottleneck for development; **we get more
> pull requests than we can review and test on short notice. Please be
> patient and help out by testing other people's pull requests, and
> remember this is a security-critical project** where any mistake might
> cost people lots of money.

Whatever.

Quark uses six hash functions in parallel.  In cryptography, more is not always better.  And the 64-bit protection is not robust.

Quark is not widely accepted and its official feed listed on Twitter goes to an [empty webpage](http://www.qrk.cc/). Quark does not inspire confidence and it looks as if it has been thrown together.  Given the very evident disorder of everything  Quark, and the rather limited security (64-bit), I would be wary.  A further note:  Wikipedia is not a source of peer-reviewed information!  It is often unreliable!